# Why a same html page directly in the machine running and IIS is not the same as display result?

Tags: html

I Have a static HTML Page,Running in local Machine input the "C:\test.html" In IE8 .everything is work fine.

But When i deploy on IIS and by : "http://localhost/test.html"

This is a big difference display result between of two way.
I am sure i use IE8 and same page.

Comment: Please elaborate on your problem.

Comment: Can you provide more information about what is different?  How about some of the html or a few screen shots?  What browser are you using?

Comment: My car is not running. What is wrong with it? It is a red Opel.

Comment: Hi,just the layout display difference.I suspect that the W3C standards?But fireFox and IE6 IE7 work fine.

Answer (score 0):

In your html file you could be using a path to your CSS file that is not visible when hosting from your local server.

Comment: just the layout display difference ,all pictures show normal.

Answer (score 0):

without any code or anything, it's hard to say.  do you have any references to any files (css, js, img, etc) that are not located where the html file is looking?

Comment: Hi,it's a big html page,i will put it  on the Web.